# [JPA][JBoss7.1] - Java extends class 2 Id for two tables with JPA Annotation

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, jboss7.x

I have a question on a design problem as follow:

1. Template Class contain basic information
2. Subscription Class which extends Template class

Is it possible to have both IDs 
- 1 id field for Template 
- 1 id field for Subscription

There are two Classes, and there should be two tables stores in DB and persisted.
My design is that: the Template is reusable and persisted and the system can create Subscription object copy form Template class and Subscrption class use a generated Id which different from Template.

So the 'Template' need an Id and 'Subscription' need another Id for my application.

Thanks so much for help.

and the coding as follow:

Template.class

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Table(name="template")
public class Template implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 12345234567867890L;


@Id @GeneratedValue(generator="hibernate-uuid.hex")
@GenericGenerator(name="hibernate-uuid.hex",strategy = "uuid.hex")
@Column(name="id",length = 40)
protected String id;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "template_attribute",length = 32)
protected String template_atrribute;
  ... 
 getter and setter and constructor
```

And with my code for Subscription Class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@javax.persistence.TableGenerator(name="SID",.................)
@Table(name="user_subscription")
public class UserSubscription extends Template implements Serializable{

@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="SID")
@Column(name="subscriptionId",length = 11)
protected Integer subscriptionId;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "start_date")
protected Date startDate;

//getter and setting and constructor
```

}